# Zend_Db with Type Decimal

Tags: zend-framework, decimal, zend-db, zero-pad

I have MySQL database for store data. Some field is type decimal. I don't know why zend_db always fill zero pad for decimal type field.

```
public function getListings() {
    $select = $this->getDb()->select()
                            ->from($this->_tableName, array('listing_sell_price', 'listing_sell_total_price'));
    return $select->query()->fetchAll();
```

}

When I try to var_dump all data from model

```
$listings = RW_Model_Listing::getInstance()->getListings();
var_dump($listings);
```

There is zero padding

```
array(2) {
        [0]=> array(2) { ["listing_sell_price"] => string(10) "0004750000", ["listing_sell_total_price"] => string(10) "0004750000"}   
        [1]=> array(2) { ["listing_sell_price"] => string(10) "0000008000", ["listing_sell_total_price"] => string(10) "0000008000"} 
    }
```

Any solution for removing zero pad ?

Best regard,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Okay it's my stupidity.

I forgot to uncheck ZeroFill in my Table Configuration LoL